# How do I write Web Application for a Delphi Server?

Tags: asp.net, delphi

I have a Delphi Application with a Client-Server Architecture. Now, I want to write a Web-application for this Delphi Client-Server Application. 
To write a this Web App I don't want to use Delphi - I want to use a "modern" Web Architecture like a PHP Framework, ASP.NET, Ruby on Rails etc.
So far i came to one possible Solution with RemObjects (http://www.remobjects.com/ro/) and ASP.NET:
[image: ASP.NET <-> Delphi]

In this approach the Delphi Application communicates with an ASP.NET WebServer over RemObjects where the Delphi Application is the REM Objects Server and the ASP.NET App is the Client.

My questions are:

1. Is this approach really a good idea and if not why?
2. What are other possible approaches to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
Thank you for your answers so far!

Comment: This is a matter of debate... One question: how are your Delphi Client and Server talking to each other?

Comment: @Arnaud Bouchez Over Rem Objects

Comment: OP: I think he was asking about the existing system.  i.e. how does the existing client/server communication work?  ODBC? SQL*Net? Raw Sockets? SOAP?

Comment: @Chris Thornton The Client Server Communication works over Rem Objects (TCP), too. ;)

Comment: @frugi In this case, I would probably stick with R/O at first. And only change the protocol in case of performance or stability issues.

Answer (score 1):

How about establishing a neutral link like a Database?

Comment: in general a good idea. But on the server there are some functions that make complex operations. If i could reuse these server functions on my web app that would make my live much easier.

Comment: A database is not a solution for all communication problems (think push / pull notifications)

Comment: @mjn: depends on db server. Very simple push notifications (string events) is available on Intebase before 1998. Pull is based on polling and this can really be a problem.

Comment: @FabricioAraujo yes, InterBase database events are a way but very limited, actually these 'strings' are always empty - the server can not send any more data than just 'event eventname_x just happened, now you have figure out in which record number', which means the client has to poll now, like checking helper tables for new entries ... (lots of stuff which should not be in a database imho)

Comment: @mjn, the fact is: the database is the most stable component of any architecture as it does respond to the questions (aka queries) of clients regardless of the its' origins (OO, procedural, native code, managed code, blablabla).  That's why many would love to incorporate that features in databases.

Comment: @FabricioAraujo adding these features as extensions can also reduce stability - if they run in the context of the server, it is easy to block or crash the system

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be SOAP, or a RESTful connection.

R/O is faster than SOAP, for sure, and well integrated to both sides (Delphi and C#).

And, since you are already using R/O between Delphi client and Server, it will be the first option to consider.

IMHO any RESTful connection between Delphi Server and a C# client may do the work also. And will probably be faster, so is to be considered only in a second phase, if you find any performance or stability problem with a R/O connection.

Answer (score 1):

You need a two-way messaging / inter process communication solution. Typically SOAP, REST and other web services (RemObjects) are synchronous, request-response style communication.

A messaging middleware can be implemented in a way which totally decouples the applications so that you can restart any part of the system (for example for maintenance and update installation) without disturbing the others.

Popular open source products in this field are for example Apache ActiveMQ, Open Message Queue and RabbitMQ, which offer cross-platform/cross language clients.

Comment: Habari looks not that bad.

Comment: @frugi Thank You! Now that you mentioned them, I have to add that I am the author of these Delphi clients libraries.